# incorporating 'try' into scraping email addresses from list of url's saved in csv file

Tags: python

I'm looking to build a scraper from a list of url's I have saved in a CSV or JSON format. It is not for spam, I have a large list which I don't want to visit one by one!
My goal is to have a script which searches the url list, connecting to the website and scrapes it for email addresses. The end goal is to save the url and email in a xls file with rows for each businesses data such as:

[image]

| business 1 url | business 1 email contact.|

| business 2 url | business 2 email contact.|

business 1 url = b1url

Ideally the script will:

1. look at b1url, search for email address, if not on page, look on contact us page,

It can do this by either searching for @website.com on the page or searching the html for [href*=mailto] in the page.

2. move to b2url, after b1url + b1url contact us page has been searched, rinse and repeat for the list.
3. If the script could source the webpage name, as another column it would be very helpful but it is not necessary.

```
iimport pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4
import re


src_df = pd.read_csv('C:/src_file.csv')

def get_email(soup):
    try:
        email = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)', response.text)[-1]
        return email
    except:
        pass

    try:
        email = soup.select("a[href*=mailto]")[-1].text
    except:
        print ('Email not found')
        email = ''
        return email


for i, row in src_df.iterrows():
    url = 'http://www.' + row['website']
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    except:
        print ('Unsucessful: ' + str(response))
        continue

    
    email = get_email(soup)


    src_df.loc[i,'Email'] = email
    print ('website:%s\nemail: %s\n' %(url, email))

src_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

If there is no email in the home page, I want the script to search the  'contact us' page or 'contact', or 'about', or 'about us page'. If it could do this after the rest of list of url's have been searched this would be good, such as if email = No Value, search 'b1url.com/contact' it would be better to reduce the chance of being blocked. The code below contains the 'try' function which I want to integrate in the above code.

```
        # Check if there is any email address in the homepage. 
        emails = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('.*@'+domain[1]+'.'+domain[2].replace("/","")))
        emails.sort(key=len)
        print(emails[0].replace("\n",""))
        final_result = emails[0]
    except:
        # Searching for Contact Us Page's url.
        try:
            flag = 0
            for link in links:
                if "contact" in link.get("href") or "Contact" in link.get("href") or "CONTACT" in link.get("href") or 'contact' in link.text or 'Contact' in link.text or 'CONTACT' in link.text:
                    if len(link.get("href"))>2 and flag<2:
                        flag = flag + 1
                        contact_link = link.get("href")

        except:
            pass

        domain = domain[0]+"."+domain[1]+"."+domain[2]
        if(len(contact_link)<len(domain)):
            domain = domain+contact_link.replace("/","")
        else:
            domain = contact_link

        try:
            # Check if there is any email address in the Contact Us Page. 
            res = requests.get(domain)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
            emails = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('.*@'+mailaddr[7:].replace("/","")))
            emails.sort(key=len)
            try:
                print(emails[0].replace("\n",""))
                final_result = emails[0]
                return final_result
            except:
                pass
        except Exception as e:
            pass

    return ""
```